# Integrate Keycloak SSO with multiple ASP.NET MVC (.Net Framework 4.7) projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, keycloak

I'm integrating Keycloak with my .Net Framework 4.7 MVC projects. Since there is no direct Keycloak client for .Net, I'm using the "[Owin.Security.Keycloak-3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Owin.Security.Keycloak-3)" NuGet for this.

My requirement is like this.

[image: Requirement]

I have two different web solutions (different domain names eg: abc.com and xyz.com). In Keycloak each one has unique client Ids but they are within the same Realm. I want to handle the SSO with Keycloak so that once you log in to Web 1, you should be able to access Web 2 without login in again to Web 2 and vice versa.

Eg:
The user logs Web 1 with his credentials. Then a moment later he loads Web 2 and it should automatically bypass the login screen in Web 2.

This is my Startup classes in both Web 1 and Web 2.

```
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "keycloak_auth"
            });

            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType("keycloak_auth");

            app.UseKeycloakAuthentication(new KeycloakAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Realm = "myProjectRealm",
                ClientId = clientId, 
                ClientSecret = clientSecret,
                KeycloakUrl = KeycloakUrl, // "http://localhost:8080"
                AuthenticationType = "keycloak_auth",
                AllowUnsignedTokens = false,
                DisableIssuerSigningKeyValidation = true,
                DisableIssuerValidation = true,
                DisableAudienceValidation = true,
                TokenClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)
            });
```

In the Controller class, I have added the [Authorize] attribute.

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ..................
    }
```

However, I implemented the above and still, have to re-login to Web 2 even though I already logged in to Web 1 a few moments ago.

Since I'm new to Keycloak, I don't understand how the Keycloak SSO should work. Do you see if I missed something in the above implementation to achieve my goal?